# Find the maximum or minimum y-value of the quadratic function by completing the square.

Tags: quadratics, completing-the-square

I have a question that reads: "Find the Minimum or Maximum (state which it is) y-value of the following quadratic function by completing the square..." Followed by the equation:

$y = \dfrac{2}{3}{x}^{2} + \dfrac{5}{4}x - \dfrac{1}{3}$

(FYI the answer key says: $- \dfrac{353}{384}$)

I'm not really sure how to start this, because when I make all the denominators common, I can't really find a way to factor out the **a** coefficient. Any help with this?

Comment: Try multiplying both sides by 12 first (that's the least common multiple of the denominators you're dealing with), so you have $12y = 8x^2+15x-4$, then factor out the 8 so you have $12y = 8(x^2 +\frac{15}{8}x)-4$, that's an easy way to handle the fractions initially. Then just keep going with completing the square like you normally would on the right hand side.